# Enable Diagnostics Log in Azure Resources using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-diagnostics

I am trying to enable Azure Diagnostics Logs in Azure Web App and pass the same to OMS workspace. Following is my code

```
$workspaceName = 'TestLogTelemetary'
$ResourceGroupName = 'TestLogTelemetaryRg'
$oms=Get-AzureRmOperationalInsightsWorkspace -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $workspaceName
$WSID = $oms.ResourceId
$resource = Get-AzureRmResource -Name "TestWebApp" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
$resourceId = $resource.ResourceId

Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $resourceId -WorkspaceId $WSID -Enable $True
```

My Powerhsell code is getting executed successfully but Diagnostics Logs are not getting enabled in TestWebApp.

Kindly let me know if any more settings needs to be configured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, [Diagnostics setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-of-diagnostic-logs#how-to-enable-collection-of-diagnostic-logs) seems **not** support Azure web app.

Refer to : [Supported services, categories, and schemas for diagnostic logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-diagnostic-logs-schema).

Per my test, I can reproduce your issue for web app, but the same command, it works fine for e.g. Azure logic app.

[image]

Also, you could find there is no azure web app in **Monitor**-> **Diagnostics settings**-> **Resource Type**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply , do we have any other Logging mechanism which can be implemented for Azure Web App

Comment: @kartikiyer Yes, but it seems that you need to manually set them in the portal. There are different types of the log, like app log and server log. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JGdw.png

Comment: I am looking to enable Logs using Powershell not from portal , do we have any provision for that

Comment: @kartikiyer May be the [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/akashkhandelwal/2018/06/25/azure-app-services-setting-diagnostic-logs-in-azure-webapps-using-powershell/) will help.